# React Renders Before Props Recieved

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, react-props, use-effect

I am using MapBox to display a map on a user profile. The component receives the props of location but the mapbox tries to render the map with the location before the props are recieved, breaking the page. I have used a workaround to make it work... but not sure if I am doing it right - do you have any recommendations? My workaround was to set the viewPort state using the useEffect Hook... this forces the map to wait a second before loading allowing time to receive props. I have a feeling that it can still break if props are not received in time though.

I'd like to also use the user's location as the center point of map, which is currently being set in the useEffect hook - but I cant get the props before it is set. Thanks!

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Geocode from "react-geocode";
import ReactMapGL, { Marker } from 'react-map-gl';
import { Label, Input, Card, Badge, Button, InputGroup,
} from 'reactstrap';

// set response language. Defaults to english.
Geocode.setLanguage("en");

// set response region. Its optional.
// A Geocoding request with region=es (Spain) will return the Spanish city.
Geocode.setRegion("es");

// set Google Maps Geocoding API for purposes of quota management. Its optional but recommended.
Geocode.setApiKey("******************************");

export default function Location(props) {
    const [ city, setCity ] = useState('');
    const [ viewPort, setViewport ] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setViewport({
                latitude: 37.0902,
                longitude: -95.7129,
                width: '100%',
                height: '200px',
                zoom: 3
            })
        },1000)

    }, [])

    const captureCity = (e) => {
        setCity(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleLocationInput = () => {
        // Get latidude & longitude from address.
        Geocode.fromAddress(city).then(
            response => {
            const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
            putLocation(lat, lng);
            },
            error => {
            console.error(error);
            }
        );
    }

    const putLocation = (lat, lon) => {
        props.updateBandLocation([lat,lon]);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="w-100">
                <ReactMapGL 
                    className="mt-2 mb-4 rounded"
                    style={{zIndex: "2"}}
                    {...viewPort} 
                    mapboxApiAccessToken={"******************"}
                    onViewportChange={viewport => setViewport(viewport)}
                    mapStyle="mapbox://styles/nickisyourfan/ck8ylgfk90kcb1iqoemkes76u"
                    >
                            <Marker latitude={props.bandLocation[0]} longitude={props.bandLocation[1]}>

                                <img src="/MapMarker.svg" alt="Band Icon" style={{width: "35px", height: "35px"}}/>

                            </Marker>

                </ReactMapGL> 
            </div>

            <Card color="dark" className="mb-1">
                <InputGroup className="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                    <Label className="d-flex flex-column text-light h3 mt-2 align-self-center">Location</Label>
                    <Input type="text" onChange={captureCity} className="d-flex align-self-center w-75 mb-2"/>
                    <Button onClick={handleLocationInput} className="w-75 align-self-center mb-2">Set Location</Button>
                </InputGroup>
            </Card>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? Which props are you expecting that aren't there? As for your actual question, you appear to have an async request, so why not use `useEffect` to capture that? That is, put the `Geocode.fromAddress` call in your `useEffect` hook and `setViewport` in the body of the `then` from that promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use setTimeout in this scenario.

I would simply not render the map until I have all the expected data for the map. 
I would add this above my return statement.

```
if (!props.bandLocation.length || !props.bandLocation[0] || !props.bandLocation[1]) {
return <MyCustomLoadingComp />
}
```

And in your specific case, I'm not sure which prop exactly the map needs or the data structure, but you can get the concept. For example, if props.bandLocation[0] is an empty object, it will still flag true, so you must change the if statement to match the data you're receiving.

Update: 
You would want to use something like a 'usePrevious' helper function. Similar to componentWillReceiveProps, you need to update something in your UI only when you get a certain item. So in this case you could check if you got a valid lat/long, then set it with useState. I needed to replicate this lifecycle method with hooks, and I adapted from this https://usehooks.com/usePrevious/. However, it is still recommended, to simply use props directly. You can pass in the name of your prop into useEffect, and when it changes the comp will re render.

So

```
const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(lat);
  useEffect(() => {
setLoaded(false);
if (isAValidLocation(props.lat)) {
  setLoaded(true);

}
}, [props.lat, props.long]);
```

However, to be blunt, you should just not render you map until it has all relevant data, you shouldn't need to use any lifecycle hooks if you aren't manipulating the props contents in any manner.

Comment: Beautiful! The render is working without the timeout! Awesome. I'd also love to change the useEffect to use the same props for latitude and longitude - It has the same problem. The props are not there before the useEffect sets the viewPort. Any suggestions? Here is the useEffect I'd like to use.  useEffect(() => {
        setViewport({
            latitude: props.bandLocation[0],
            longitude: props.bandLocation[1],
            width: '100%',
            height: '200px',
            zoom: 3
        })
    }, [])